# how to free a pointer after it returned its content

Tags: c

Here is my code, how can I free `new_double_size` after it is called. I am a beginner in C, so thanks for help.

```
size_t get_doubled_size(Vector *vtr, size_t new_size){
   size_t *new_double_size = malloc(sizeof(size_t));
   *new_double_size = vtr -> capacity;
   while(new_size > *new_double_size){
     *new_double_size *= 2;
   }
   return *new_double_size;
}
```

and in another place, i call this like:

```
int doubled_size = get_doubled_size(....);
```

Comment: You can't with the way your code is currently structured. `new_double_size` needs to be returned to the caller. But why dynamically allocate memory at all? Just use static memory. That is: `size_t new_double_size = blah; return new_double_size;`.

Comment: @AlanAu wouldn't that be deleted after the function exit since it is on the stack?

Comment: The variable itself no longer exists when the function exits. But that is not relevant. The [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) ensures the return value gets back to the caller. What you can't do is return an address of a function local variable: `int i; return &i;`. In this case the address of `i` is returned correctly but it can not be used in any meaningful way as `i` no longer exists (out of scope).

Comment: You don't show all your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, you need to get its value before freeing it, e.g.:

```
size_t return_value = *new_double_size;
free(new_double_size);
return return_value;
```

But in this case, you don't even need to allocate space for the new size... just use a `size_t` variable directly.

Answer (score 2):

You should only use `malloc` when you want to control lifetime of a variable. In this case you do not need to do that, and you can write much more simply:

```
size_t get_doubled_size(Vector *vtr, size_t new_size)
{
     size_t new_double_size = vtr -> capacity;
     while(new_size > new_double_size)
         new_double_size *= 2;
     return new_double_size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help, since we don't know what a `Vector` is.

I would recommend using [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) and have each function which *changes* or mutates your vector return a new vector, if it ends with a flexible array member.

Or at least have a `void grow_vector(Vector*vec, unsigned newsize)`  function.

In general, in C, you should have well documented conventions about [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), and *document* who is responsible of freeing memory. Often you create constructor and destructor functions.

Answer (score -1):

The variable itself no longer exists when the function exits. But that is not relevant. The [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) ensures the return value gets back to the caller. What you can't do is return an address of a function local variable:

```
int *foo( void ) {
   int i = 42; 
   return &i;
}
```

In this case the address of `i` is returned correctly but it cannot be used in any meaningful way as `i` no longer exists (is out of scope) after the function returns.

<sub>The text of this answer came from a comment by Alan Au.</sub>

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question

Comment: OP thinks you told him he doesn't need to free the memory, when in fact his code has a memory leak

Comment: @M.M Hmm, OP told you this, did he?

Comment: That's what I get from reading what happened. This answer does not address OP's code *at all*. Calling conventions are irrelevant. There are no local variables having their address taken. There are no pointers being returned.  OP's code is wrong and this answer does not point out the mistake, nor suggest a fix.

Comment: @M.M And yet this answer got three upvotes in the comments, and a hearty "Thx!!!!" from the OP, before I converted it from a comment to a community wiki. Which you were free to improve, BTW.

Comment: My suggested improvement would be to delete since it does not answer the question, doesn't indicate the mistake OP made, and doesn't suggest a fix.